# Dangling present participle

Tags: dangling-participles

The following sentence sounds normal, but I would like to ask if it has a correct structure or is it dangling participle because the subject of the main clause is "the doctor" whereas that of participle phrase is "the number of surgeries."

> **The doctor** says **the number of surgeries** he performs on people with
>   cancer is now low, approaching the level before the incident.

Answer (score 2):

This is fine. All syntactic and semantic cues point to *the number of surgeries &c* as the subject/predicand<sup>†</sup> of the participle clause

1. The clause to which the participle clause is attached is not the headed by *says* but the clause headed by *is*, whose subject is *the number of surgeries &c*.
2. We ordinarily 'track' not to the subject of the head clause but to the nearest semantically plausible NP to find the subject of a participle clause; in this case the nearest NP is *the number of surgeries &c*. (Moreover, *the doctor* as the subject/predicand of *approaching &c* is semantically implausible.)
3. The participle clause is juxtaposed to *low* and semantically is obviously a supplement enlarging on the meaning of that adjective—which is, again, the predicate complement of the clause headed by *is* and is ascribed by that clause to its subject, *the number of surgeries &c*.

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>In this case, where the clause acts as an adjective and the verb is a bare copula, subject and predicand are the same entity.</sub>